# Saltarse un setInterval

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, setinterval

```js
$(function(){ 
   var i = 0;
   var myVar = setInterval(function(){
   $('#numero').html(i);
          i++;
   }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="numero"></div>
<button id="boton">pulsame</button>
```

Que podría hacer para que al pulsar el botón "pulsame" el div con id "numero" pasase al siguiente numero sin que haga falta esperar los 5 segundos y que luego siga cada 5 segundos?

Comment: Antes de entrar al interval mostrar ese valor en el dom e incrementar `$('#numero').html(i++);` según entiendo

Comment: Da igual que empieze por 1 o 0, quiero que al pulsar "pulsame" se pase al siguiente numero y luego siga mostrando el siguiente cada 5 segundos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que limpiar el intervalo y lanzar uno nuevo. 
Para seguirle la pista definís una variable que lo contenga y así podes limpiarlo y redefinirlo.

Aquí hay un borrador de como podes implementarlo.

```js
var i = 0;
function cuenta(){
   $('#numero').html(i);
   i++;
}

var myTimer;

function empezarCuenta(n){
  i = n;
  clearInterval(myTimer);
  myTimer = setInterval(cuenta, 5000);
}

$(function(){ 
   $('#boton').click(function(){cuenta();empezarCuenta(i);});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="numero"></div>
<button id="boton">pulsame</button>
```

i, myTimer y cuenta quedan por fuera para ser mas globales

una solución mas elegante podes encontrarla aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8126466/1423096

Comment: Es un ejemplo interesante pero creo que no responde a mi duda, yo quisiera que al pulsar se pase al siguiente numero, por ejemplo si va por el 5 y yo pulso el botón se pase a 6, y luego continué cada cinco segundos con los siguientes números.

Comment: ahí le saque el `i=0;` y empieza la cuenta desde el siguiente. la mecánica es la misma, reseteas el intervalo y lanzas uno nuevo.